# Как передать параметры по ajax?

Tags: jquery, ajax

Как передать 3 параметра CSRF_TOKEN ,msg, id по ajax ?

```
<meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}" />


function send() {
  var CSRF_TOKEN = $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content');
  var msg   = $('#formsend').serialize();
  var id = $('form.new_add').attr('name');
    $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url: '{{route('menu.store')}}',
      data: msg +"&qq="+ id +"&_token="+ CSRF_TOKEN, 
        success: function(data) {

         },
      error:  function(xhr, str){

      }
    });
}
```

Comment: таким способом не передается, а просто страница обновляется

Answer (score 1):

```
 function send() {
var CSRF_TOKEN = $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content');
var msg   = $('#formsend').serialize();
var id = $('form.new_add').attr('name');
$.ajax({
  type: 'POST',
  url: '{{route('menu.store')}}',
  data: {"msg":msg, "id": id ,"CSRF_TOKEN": CSRF_TOKEN},
  success: function(data) {

  },
  error:  function(xhr, str){

  }
});
```

}

Answer (score 1):

```
var data = new FormData($('#formsend')[0]);
data.append("id", id);
data.append("CSRF_TOKEN", CSRF_TOKEN);
$.ajax({
  type: 'POST',
  url: '{{route('menu.store')}}',
  data: data,
  ...
```

Но у Вас какие-то другие проблемы, если страница обновляется. Покажите, как вызывается функция `send`.